# Why doesn't my whole wheat dough pass the Poke Test?

Tags: dough, flour

http://www.thekitchn.com/bread-baking-tip-how-to-tell-w-156772

> The Poke Test - Give that ball of dough a firm poke with your finger. If the indentation fills back quickly, you're good to go. If it stays looking like a deep dimple, continue kneading.

I use the water and the whole wheat flour only. After kneading the dough for 15 minutes I poked it. The hole didn't fill up.

Is there a proper way to knead the dough which I may be missing?

This dough is supposed to be used for making [Parathas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paratha) and [Chapatis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapati).

Comment: You have to knead dough made with whole-wheat flour for longer than  white flours. Keep going!

Comment: I have researched several paratha recipes, and they are fairly uniform in not mixing or kneading the dough for very long.  They may not require a lot a of glutent development.  Why do you think your dough needs to pass this test?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I want the chapati and parathas (same dough is used for both) to remain very soft til long hours.

Comment: Gluten development (or lack of it) is not going to help with that.   That is a factor of staling, and flat breads are going to stale quickly, especially if they are lean and not enriched (not loaded with fat, sugar, and so on).

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ so, what is gluten development help for w.r.t kneadable doughs?

Comment: Chewiness and structure.   Ability to hold leavening from yeast.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ so the dough with more gluten will have to be chewed for much longer to swallow it? It won't be soft as cotton? Is that what you indicate?

Comment: I don't know about the length of chewing, but it would certainly have a chewier mouth feel.

Answer (score 2):

The "spring back poke test" is a function of gluten content. Whole-wheat doughs have a hard time building gluten networks, because the sharp edges of the bran cut through the gluten strands as you knead. In general, you should never use more than 50% whole-wheat flour in a standard bread dough. *Cook's Illustrated* successfully increased that to 60% by soaking the whole-wheat flour in milk for at least 8 hours before making the dough, and using bread flour instead of all-purpose for the other 40%.

Comment: It's fascinating what happens at the microscopic level in everyday things!